# How to set full access annotation for specific method in Rest Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, annotations

Here is my Rest Service Class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/system_users")
@Secured({ "ROLE_MANAGER", "ROLE_EDITOR" })
public class SystemUsers {

@Inject
    SystemUserBo systemUserBo;

...
...
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/get_users", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public RestResponse getUser(@RequestBody String userName) {
    try {

        String[] systemUser = systemUserBo.getRecord(userName);

        return new RestResponse(systemUser);

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return new RestResponse(RestResponse.ERR_UNKNOWN);
    }
}
...
...
...
}
```

I secured other methods with ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_EDITOR and their specific tags

and i want to give full access only that method.

Which annotation should i use?

Thanks for helping.